# SQL INSERT TROUBLE

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sitting infront of this code for 2 hours i cant figure out whats wrong :(

I've been trying to have a html form which calls the php function to insert the information from the form into the database but for some reason does not work :/

**here is my form code :**

```
<?php include 'connection.php'; ?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="user_create.php" method="POST">
username: <input type="text" name="username"/>
password: <input type="text" name="password"/>
email: <input type="text" name="email"/>
<input type="submit" name='submit' value="user_create"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**database connection**

```
<?php 

//Connecting databases 

$localhost  = ""; 
$dbuser = "";
$dbpass = "m"; 
$dbname = ""; 

$connect = mysql_connect($localhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db("$dbname", $connect);  

?>
```

**my php function**

```
<?php include 'connection.php';?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $username = $_POST['username']; 
    $password = $_POST['password']; 
    $email = $_POST['email']; 


$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users( username,password,email,type) 
VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email','1')");
mysql_query($query); 
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("You have been registered");</script>';
}
else
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("jo");</script>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE users(
username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
type boolean not null default 0
);

Comment: How doesn't it work? Do you get an error? What error message do you get? What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: yeah i dont get any error it just shows the php page in the browser showing me the code which is in the php file

Comment: even when u fix all issues it will add data 2 times since u have executed the query 2 times..

Comment: If it showing you the PHP code then you don't have the web server/php installed correctly (edit: or your file isn't named .php?)

Comment: so could that mean i have to give the files permissions or  ?

Comment: you never set what db you are working with `$dbname = "";` also. `$localhost = 127.0.0.1` instead of nothing

Comment: im working from my university host so weve got all the login details checked them all of them are right

Comment: Just hope that one of your users doesn't have a nickname of "Little Bobby Tables" [http://xkcd.com/327/](http://xkcd.com/327/), or, consider addressing **SQL Injection** vulnerabilities.

Comment: 1. You're open to SQL injections. 2. Stop using `mysql_`. 3. Don't store plaintext passwords. 4. Your second `mysql_query` will fail as it uses the *result* from your first `mysql_query`. 5. Most of your DB connection variables are empty - what's up with that? 6. Don't use `"$var"` when you could use `$var`.

Comment: I'm not questioning your login credentials, but you aren't selecting a database and you're trying to connect to nothing, that simply wont work regardless of credentials.

Comment: You have absolutely **ZERO** error handling on your database calls, which means you have ZERO idea if anything is actually occuring.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: 1. But this is just for development, and shouldn't my pattern for development be the wrong way to do things? 2. But all the examples at w3schools are for mysql_, so why not get code working with a deprecated interface, and then just worry about converting a whole bunch of working code later, when it's more painful. 3. plaintext passwords are just AWESOME.  (i kid, i kid.)

Comment: @Marc B: why check for errors. I much prefer holding my pinky finger to the corner of my mouth ala Dr Evil style, and just assume that everything is going to go to plan. Mmmm?

Comment: Did you say it shows the PHP code in your browser? If this is happening the code isn't even running. Is the file on a server with PHP installed? And are you running the file via your server (i.e not just opening it in your browser)?

Comment: Try `mysql_query($query,$connect);` might just be a connection to DB issue. @user3279345

Comment: Plus remove the quotes in `mysql_select_db("$dbname", $connect);` to be `mysql_select_db($dbname, $connect);` @user3279345

Comment: @spencer7593: it also leads to situations like this. "my code isn't working, I'm too lazy to check if it actually SHOULD be working, fix it for me".

Comment: @Marc B: I agree. Exactly. No one should spend time "fixing" new code that "doesn't work", if 1) the code uses the deprecated `mysql_` interface, and 2) doesn't check the return from function calls that can return errors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should use PHP-PDO in order to avoid from SQL Injection attacks also it will fix insert trouble too.

```
<?php
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'username';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'password';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=animals", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    echo 'Connected to database<br />';

    /*** INSERT data ***/
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username,
            password,
            email,
            type) VALUES (
            :username, 
            :password, 
            :email, 
            :type)";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);      
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':type', $_POST['type'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute(); 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you connecting properly?

`$dbuser = "";`

Maybe must be "root" or other user?

Check this part :

```
//Connecting databases 

$localhost  = ""; 
$dbuser = "";
$dbpass = "m"; 
$dbname = "";
```

Comment: this credentials and database name are most likely removed trying to enhance security and not put his username and password out open to the world. when in fact if this code goes live we could get root access with simple injection.